# Why does string find not display the intended output

Tags: c++

I want to print an error message if the user's input string does not match what is intended. However, std::string::npos does not print it.

```
void AdvisorBot::printHelpCMD() {
    std::string prod ("prod");
    std::string min ("min");
    std::string max ("max");

    std::string checkInput("prod min max");


    std::cout << "\nEnter the command you need help with e.g <prod>: "  << std::endl;
    std::string cmd;
    std::getline(std::cin, cmd); //takes input and store into string cmd

    if (cmd == prod) {
        std::cout << "\nThis command lists all the available products on the exchange.\n" << std::endl;
    }    

    if (cmd.find(checkInput) != std::string::npos) { //to loop over inputted strings and check if matches above NOT WORKING
        std::cout << "\nCommand does not exist\n" << std::endl;
    }
```

Comment: That should be a `==`.

Comment: @tkausl when its `==`, the string "Commad does not exist" is printed even when the user input is correct. For example, if user types prod, the error appears

Comment: The logic in the `if` is backwards. If the returned value equals `std::string::npos` then there was no match.

Comment: The error won't appear if you input the search term, i.e. `prod min max`.

Comment: @tkausl the error message always appears

Comment: `checkInput.find(cmd)` https://godbolt.org/z/d7v98nx5M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cmd.find(checkInput)` looks for the whole string `checkInput` in `cmd` which is presumably not what you want.

If you want to check whether your string is one of a list of values `std::set` might work better:

```
#include <set>

...

std::set<std::string> checkInput { "prod", "min", "max" };
if (checkInput.find(cmd) == checkInput.end()) {
    std::cout << "\nCommand does not exist\n" << std::endl;
}
```